# ¿Por qué no me funciona la url en un background-image en React?

Tags: reactjs, json

Tengo un problema que busque muchas formas de resolver, pero no logro encontrarle la vuelta.

Paso lo que creo que puede ser parte del problema que son las carpetas y su orden.

Ese es mi source digamos, donde está todo.

Entonces, yo tengo un componente Product, que usando el JSON mapea el JSON para hacer *product cards*. Estas *product cards* tienen un *background-image*, el cual yo adquiero del "image" de JSON.

El problema radica ahi. No sé si queda claro el problema, pero en mi *div* de _Product Card? que tiene un `style background-image`, me tira un error de que no encuentra la URL , no sé realmente que es.

Probé cuanta forma de poner la URL en el .JSON hay.

Probe el require, sin el require, de mil formas y no logro ver el error.

```
import React from 'react';
import products from '../../data/products.json';
import ProductCard from '../elements/ProductCard';
import './../../styles/product.css';
function Product() {
  const productos = products.products;

  return (
    <div>
        <h1>Lista de Productos</h1>
        <h1>AAAAA</h1>
        <div className='product-grid-container'>
            {productos.map((producto) => (
                        <ProductCard productName = {producto.name} productPrice = {producto.price} key={producto.id} productImage={producto.image}>
                       
                        </ProductCard>

                    
            ))}
        </div>
        
    </div>
  );
}

export default Product;
```

El código del ProductCard:

```
import React from 'react';
import './../../styles/product-card.css';

const ProductCard = (props) => {
    const propImage = props.productImage;
    return (
        <div className='product-item product-item-grid' style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${require(propImage)})` }}>
            <div className='product-item-info'>
                <p>{props.productName}</p>
                <p>${props.productPrice}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
 
export default ProductCard;
```

Y por último el json:

```js
{
    "products": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "King T-Shirt",
        "category": "T-Shirt",
        "price": 20.99,
        "stock": 10,
        "image": "./../../images/clothes/king-t-shirt.jpg"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Orange T-Shirt",
        "category": "T-Shirt",
        "price": 20.99,
        "stock": 3,
        "image": "./../../images/clothes/orange-t-shirt.jpg"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Lana-Sweater",
        "category": "Sweater",
        "price": 24.99,
        "stock": 2,
        "image": "./../../images/clothes/lana-sweater.jpg"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Beige Top",
        "category": "Top",
        "price": 15.99,
        "stock": 15,
        "image": "./../../images/clothes/top.jpg"
      }
    ]
  }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Disculpen si no queda bien clara la pregunta, no soy muy bueno con estas cosas.